# Thin client as stand-alone Linux server?

Tags: linux, thin-client

I was wondering if someone knew of thin clients such as [those from 10Zig](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/News/10Zig-RBT602672v/) that can be reflashed to run Linux and act as a SOHO server?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question suggests you don't understand what a thin client is.

Comment: I think I do. I happen to like this compact, quiet hardware, and was wondering if some has successfully been reflashed to run as a stand-alone server for SOHO use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently have some old HP thin Clients units here, 512mb Flash and 256mb Ram...they actually already have a version of Debian on them to run up with...the limitation is obviously the size...but on some models they support external USB drive to have more space...

OS for the ones we currently have can be found > [Here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3221864&taskId=135&prodTypeId=12454&prodSeriesId=3221863&lang=en&cc=us) <

So really I would think a small enough distro to do the right task might cover what you need

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat heavier than a thin-client but here are some interesting mini-ITX or pico-ITX solutions here, some of them expensive:

http://www.logicsupply.com/

and

http://www.itxdepot.com/xcart/home.php

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself a [Sheevaplug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SheevaPlug). More powerful, just as small and quiet and probably even cheaper than a normal thin client at $99. And boy, do these babies rock.

Answer (score 1):

What I am toying with: Neoware CA22 (P640 MB, Intel PC architecture board) VIA C7 1 GHz processor up to 1 GB RAM, 15Whr power draw. 4 USB ports, 1 internal HDD interface. BIOS options to select boot order to include USB boot. eBay cost me about $12 each in 2011 when bought in qty.

See: http://www.parkytowers.me.uk/

The pages are served by a relatively under powered thin client (400 MHz) as web server. He has his experiments on many models and Linux distros too. Including server setups (webserver, samba file share, etc). TinyCore is used in some of these implimentations.

Also: http://www.thinclientforum.com/index.htm

He has done some interesting things, such as HES and NAS servers.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some neoware thin clients used as servers. They had 0.5GB of flash disk and this was enough for a small server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Wyse V50. I have the V90 which is same hardware running XPe. Max flash 2GB, max ram 1GB DDR, internal wifi option, pcmcia slot, 3 USB 2.0, dual monitor support, audio. This falls somewhere in the thin to fat client range and should be more than capable of doing what you need+++. Can be found on ebay for $60-160 depending on hardware options.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check out what's available on eBay.